# How do you use gcc's ar utility with ocaml's compiler?

Tags: ocaml

I can create a static library with ocaml object files using

```
ar rc ./lib/libprog.a ./_build/*.cmo
```

And I can display the contents of the libprog.a using

```
ar t ./lib/libprog.a
```

but I can't find any documentation that explains how to use this static library with ocaml's compilers.

Could someone please post an example(or provide a link) which demonstrates how to use a libprog.a file with ocaml's compilers. Please no examples with ocaml build utilities because I want to see how its done at the command line using ocaml's compilers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml wants to use its own archive format.

```
$ cat a.ml
let x = 14
$ cat b.ml
let y = 17
$ cat main.ml
let () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (A.x + B.y)

$ ocamlc -c a.ml
$ ocamlc -c b.ml
$ ocamlc -a -o oclibab.cma a.cmo b.cmo
```

Now there is an OCaml archive (.cma file) named oclibab.cma that contains the modules A and B:

```
$ ocamlobjinfo oclibab.cma
File oclibab.cma
Force custom: no
Extra C object files:
Extra C options:
Extra dynamically-loaded libraries:
Unit name: A
Interfaces imported:
    9b04ecdc97e5102c1d342892ef7ad9a2    Pervasives
    79ae8c0eb753af6b441fe05456c7970b    CamlinternalFormatBasics
    b162d96cf09fcde9d245f96359c9178a    A
Required globals:
Uses unsafe features: no
Force link: no
Unit name: B
Interfaces imported:
    9b04ecdc97e5102c1d342892ef7ad9a2    Pervasives
    79ae8c0eb753af6b441fe05456c7970b    CamlinternalFormatBasics
    bc583fd68fc2b0a4e44e3e640983c8dd    B
Required globals:
Uses unsafe features: no
Force link: no
```

Note that this archive format contains digital signatures for the interfaces. This allows stronger checking at link time than is generally available through the stock toolchain of the OS (like ar).

```
$ ocamlc -o main oclibab.cma main.ml
$ ./main
31
```

Comment: So all the *.a files that are included with Ocaml are C files? Example unix.a.

Comment: If you make an archive of bytecode (.cmo) files, ocamlc makes a .cma file. If you make an archive of native (.cmx) files, ocamlopt makes a .cmxa file *and* a .a file. So not all .a files are from .c sources. Some of them are, most likely.